# Draw circles on map with fixed radius

Tags: draw, netlogo, geometry

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm wanting to draw a circle with radius r on a position on the map with coordinates [x,y]
All the variables are known. Its literally the function/procedure that draws/displays a circle on the map I'm unsure about.
I'd ideally not want a turtle to draw it and not have it by colouring set patches.
Any ideas will help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a smooth circle drawn in the draw layer? If that is the case, I *think* you would need to have a turtle draw it. However, as far as I know the drawing layer is inaccessible to turtles, so it would just be for visual effect. If you need to use the circle for other purposes would `ask patch 0 0 [ ask patches in-radius 8  [ set pcolor red ] ]` do the trick? Goes against your "colouring set patches" constraint, though.

Comment: A smooth circle would be good. Isn't needed by anything else, simply for visual effect and to highlight certain areas for the user. Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you:

- make a new turtle, and have the turtle:

  - set its shape to a circle shape
  - position itself where you want it and set its size appropriately
  - `stamp`
  - `die`

Presto, you now have a circle in the drawing layer.

Comment: Simple, fast, and does exactly what is needed. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, I don't know of a way to draw in the drawing layer without a turtle (or the GIS extension, which would be much more complicated). So, if you end up deciding to use a turtle, you can check out the [Turtles Circling](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/TurtlesCircling) model in the Model Library for detail. You can also have a look at the code below for a simple example of a turtle drawing a circle based on your chosen patch coordinates and circle radius.

```
to circle

  let cx 0                ;; x coordinate of patch you want to circle
  let cy 0                ;; y coordinate of patch you want to circle
  let r 10                ;; radius of the circle you want
  let p2r ( 2 * pi * r )  ;; get circumference of the circle
  let step p2r / 360      ;; make step lengths 1/360th of the circumference

  crt 1 [                 ;; create a single drawing turtle
    setxy cx + r cy       ;; move it to the highlight patch + the radius
    pd                    ;; put the pen down
    set heading 0         ;; make it face along the tangent
    while [ p2r > 0 ] [   ;; make the turtle continue to move until the circle is drawn
      lt 1                
      fd step            
      set p2r p2r - step    
    ]
    die                   ;; remove the turtle
  ]

end
```

Comment: Thanks again for this, much appreciated. I used your original idea of the patch and updated it to show shades of red, effectively the size of the circle I was originally asking about. That works and isn't worth a lot of effort to use GIS like you said. Many thanks :)

Comment: Good thinking! Happy coding.